# Finding the column where the data is found

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE :value IN(col1, col2, col3)
```

where it finds the value of my php variable in three columns in a table.
How can I know where the value is found from col1, col2 and col3?
Or is there any other way I can get the same results?

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT *,
     CASE WHEN col1 = :value THEN 'COL1'
          WHEN col2 = :value THEN 'COL2'
          ELSE 'COL3'
     END AS EXIST_IN
FROM table 
WHERE :value IN (col1, col2, col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a row is returned after executing query, it also returns column names. A column which contains searched value, will have value, others will show NULL.

So to check it, either you can use server-side programming to check column name from returned row, or use if-else or cases in SQL.

Comment: this is only partly true. some methods like `mysqli_fetch_row` only return enumerated rows, but a method like `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns as an associated array